# Having difficulty getting images from sdcard and displaying in gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I seem to have a problem loading images into my gallery from sdcard.  I know I am doing something wrong with the code but don't know what.  Can anyone please help me.

here is my GalleryActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

Cursor cursor;

String[] imageIDs = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
GalleryActivity(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageIDs, null, null,    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
cursor = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
{
};
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
            int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic" + (position + 1)  + "selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    int itemBackground;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
{
        context = c;

        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId (R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground,0);
        a.recycle();
}

    public int getCount() {
        return imageIDs.length;
}

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
}

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
}

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    imageView = new ImageView(context);
                    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageIDs));

                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
                } else {
                    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                }
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
                return imageView;
    }
}
}
```

The error is under this bit of code which is to retrieve the images from the cdcard (Is this the correct code for retrieving images from sdcard?)

```
 String[] imageIDs = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
 GalleryActivity(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageIDs, null, null,   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
 cursor = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
```

Hope anyone can help me?

Comment: The errors im getting are under "null, null" and under the dot in "Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);" and getting a error under "IMAGE_ID-error-);    The errors are : Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ",", delete this token
 - Syntax error on tokens, FormalParameter expected 
  instead
 - Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this 
  token
 - Syntax error on token ".", ... expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ( expected

Comment: Oh man, a simple java compiler error?! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

These code lines have go into a method. You have them written outside any method.

```
GalleryActivity(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageIDs, null, null,   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
 cursor = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
```